# Parent form gets Activated after pressing Enter

Tags: c#, forms

I have a main form with lots of bar items, and every one of them opens a new form when clicked (or using custom made shortcut). So, child form opens and gets focus for user to enter data.

However, if I navigate to the bar item by arrows, and then press Enter my child form opens BUT parent form gets activated (Activated event gets fired) and gets focus.
This of course does not happen if the child is Modal, but I can't use that for all forms.

```
if (ownerForm != null)
{
     form.Show(ownerForm);
 }
else
{
     form.Show();
 }
```

Comment: Did you try to call the [Activate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activate.aspx) method on your child form ?

Comment: What "bar items" do you mean? If I do the same you are using a default button or a ToolStripButton, it works fine. I'd guess you use some custom/special control that behaves incorrectly when activating it using `Enter`.

Comment: I use normal DevExpress BarButtonItem, nothing custom about it. I do set BringToFront on the child, just after these Show commands, but that's about it.
Activate doesn't work because the form is Activated at this point, but the parent form gets activated after it.